# How to retrieve listed form parameters by laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to retrieve listed form parameters in next page by laravel.

The following code is just example for explain simply.

```
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="cat_a" value="Category A">

    <input type="text" name="cat_b[0]" value="Category B0">
    <input type="text" name="cat_b[1]" value="Category B1">
    <input type="text" name="cat_b[2]" value="Category B2">
  </form>
```

I can get cat_a on next page from parameter `Request $request` like `$request->cat_a`.
However I have no idea how to get `cat_b`s.

Please give me advice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

remove numbers in 'name' of `input` tag,

```
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="cat_a" value="Category A">

    <input type="text" name="cat_b[]" value="Category B0">
    <input type="text" name="cat_b[]" value="Category B1">
    <input type="text" name="cat_b[]" value="Category B2">
  </form>
```

get `cat_b` values and get each value by foreach.

```
$catsB = $request->cat_b;
foreach($catsB as $catB) {
   // do something
}
```

I hope be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it works...

```
$cat_b_array = $request->cat_b;
foreach($cat_b_array as $cat_b_value) {
   echo $cat_b_value;
}
```

Comment: I had same errors previous one `ErrorException Undefined offset: 0`. I guess something wrong. I have null check.

Comment: you can `print_r($request->cat_b);` and check the array keys...

Answer (score 0):

You can get your list of values with this code
    $cat_b_list = $request->input('cat_b.*')

Also you can get specific value by replacing * by array key